# Android - The listview is not updating when I use searchview

Tags: java, android, listview, searchview

I am novice in Android Studio, can someone help me with my problem. After I use searchview, when I delete a item in the listview it is not updating.

Let me give you the screenshot to better visualize the problem

[This is the look of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf1Us.png)

[The filter works and it shows the Lemon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSVxm.png)

[After using the searchview, I try to delete the Lemon with the toast message but it is still in the listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wmcX.png)

1. Here's what I been working on so far

**Main activity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    EditText item, price;

    Button add;

    ListView listView;
    SearchView searchBox;
    ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> searchList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        item = findViewById(R.id.edtProdName);
        price = findViewById(R.id.edtPrice);
        add = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.list);
        searchBox = findViewById(R.id.searchView);

        itemList = FileHelper.readData(this);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, itemList);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String prodName = item.getText().toString();
                String prodPrice = price.getText().toString();
                String product = prodName.toUpperCase() +  " " + "P" +  prodPrice.toUpperCase();
                itemList.add(product);
                item.setText("");
                price.setText("");
                FileHelper.writeData(itemList,getApplicationContext());
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Collections.sort(itemList);
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                alert.setTitle("Delete");
                alert.setMessage("Do you want to delete this product from the list?");
                alert.setCancelable(false);
                alert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        itemList.remove(position);
                        FileHelper.writeData(itemList, getApplicationContext());
                        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Deleted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });

        searchBox.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
            {
                arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }

        });
    }
}
```

**FileHelper.Java (which let me save the data in here in my device memory)**

```
public class FileHelper
{
    public static final String FILENAME = "listinfo.dat";

    public static void writeData(ArrayList<String> item, Context context)
    {
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream oas = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oas.writeObject(item);
            oas.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static ArrayList<String> readData(Context context)
    {
        ArrayList<String> itemList = null;
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(FILENAME);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            itemList = (ArrayList<String>) ois.readObject();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            itemList = new ArrayList<>();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return itemList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hi** even if i can't explain why that didn't work, we can fix that with differents way.

- ArraysAdapters can be capricious, you can just reset it but that isn't best way.
- You can create you on adapter with new class extends BaseAdapter

That exemple how you can make that:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return itemList.get(i)
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
        String item = itemList.get(i);
        TextView textview = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textview.setText(item);

        return view;
    }
```

Hoping to have helped you,
Shayfox.

Answer (score 0):

You delete the item from the original list, but not the list in your `ArrayAdapter`. Therefore the item is still in the list, even after you call `notifyDataSetChanged`. Do:

```
...
String itemToRemove = itemList.remove(position);
arrayAdapter.remove(itemToRemove);    
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
...
```

in your positive button callback.